# MyEthereumWallet got stolen

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, private-key, wallet-transfer, phishing

2000 tenx tokens were stolen from MyEtherWallet after i transferred it. Luckily i didn't transfer everything, i wanted to test it first. I was looking for a safe wallet and decided to go ahead with MyEtherWallet. I generated my private key over the website (web-wallet) and use it.

At first i thought it was a phishing website that i got into, but then i checked my web browser history over and over again... and couldn't find any suspicious website address. I did go to the correct website www.myetherwallet.com

Secondly I tried to scan my PC for malware / virus using Norton anti-virus and found nothing.

So did the website got hacked when i used it? Any suggestion to this? Can you suggest anything to get my tokens back? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Provide your Ethereum address plz to check it out in Etherscan.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, I thought I was connected to MyEtherWallet, but it gave me a bad adress for my private key and I sent 2 Ether to somebody else.
There is absolutly no proof or evidences from my browser history which has been cleared. Like I've never been connected to any fake website...
I came on MyEtherWallet using the http windows from Firefox, putting the first letters of the site then arrow down and enter. The only link recorded in the http window history is the official one.
Odd.

Send a report to the MyEtherWallet team, with your adress, the adress that took the Ether, and any further information regarding the scam (browser history...).